# Appium inspector not identifying objects on iOS native app page that consists of a auto swipe section

Tags: appium

steps:
1. Launch appium inspector
2. Go to the iOS app page that consists of the auto-swipe section
3. Click 'Refresh' button on the appium inspector, it just shows loading icon on the Refresh button, but the appium inspector does not load any information on the UIAApplication,UIAWindow and  Details sections.
4. #3 observation is done only for app screens which has auto - swipe section.
5. Appium inspector identifies all other app screens as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Appium inspector works only when your scripts are running. In your case, try to put some long `Thread.sleep();` where your refresh is not working. Second, you can also use UIAutomator for finding the locators.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. I am trying to get the locators using UIAutomator now.